# File search across all Git projects

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2018

I am trying to search for a specific file extensions across all Git remote projects for the master branch.

Is there any command for it? Cloning all projects locally will take lot of time.

Comment: How many repositories are we talking about here. It may not take as much time as you are thinking if you do shallow clone.

Comment: There are total 34 projects and each project containss 8-10 repository on avg.

Comment: Do you have URLs of all the repos. What if we write script which does all this automatically for you. Clone and list files of interest.

Comment: but the problem is i would need to go through all 350 repos for URLs

Comment: You tagged your question both for gitlab and github. Which product are you using? You might be able to leverage features of the VCS server for this...

Comment: @sytech i didn't tag. this was edited. I am using TFS 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS 2018, I found the search by using filter by scope(file:) option. It has all the necessary filters(e.g. Branch, repo). This solved my issue. Using the same search, I able to find the string within each file.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, you have to rely on the tools provided by your host platform: Gitlab, Github or whatever.

As an alternative, you should build a list of your remote repo then remotely search by:

```bash
git log origin/master ...search options...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both GitHub and GitLab have search functionality for this.

If you need a local/`git` based solution, cloning the repo is probably your best bet, depending on what information you need from the repository contents. There is a tool called [all-repos](https://github.com/asottile/all-repos) that helps you do this. It provides a minimal configuration for discovery and automation of working with many repos all at once. It also includes tools like `all-repos-find-files`, `all-repos-grep`, etc.